# Winter bash hat appears behind photo

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

My winter hats show up behind my photo on Chrome 29.0.1547.62, Windows 7 Pro.

I would upload a picture but I've just noticed that the "Choose File" button on the upload picture dialog also doesn't work. :)

Is this the right place to be reporting this?!

**Edit**

Testing again without Deluminate add-on enabled

[image: no wig :(]

Comment: Any user scripts? Any add-ons? Looks like something is messing up the JavaScript. Does a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5) help?

Comment: Interesting. It is indeed the fault of an add-on it seems, switching off Deluminate fixes the order. Good spot :)

Comment: I use firefox, but now I tried Chrome I realized it just doesn't show any hat. I don't have any add-on installed. My Chorme version is 31.0.1650.63 m. Do I have to login to see everybody's hat?

Comment: @Math it's site specific. Here on Meta for example you will see hats even as anonymous visitor, but on Stack Overflow you must first log in and, "allow" Winterbash and only then hats will appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of @Oded posting an answer...

Turns out this is because of the Deluminate plugin, which somehow reorders the hat and the image in it's efforts to make my screen darker and therefore easier on the eyes.